# Is there way to get impression number for each Responsive Search Ads combination via Google Ads API?

Tags: google-ads-api

I'd like to generate a report with breakdown of performance metrics for each RSA combination

Answer (score 0):

Not that I'm aware of. Especially considering it's not even available beyond a very limited set of metrics in the web UI. Right now, I'm still pulling each of the assets and manually building out the ad in an ads report. Considering the push to make RSAs default, I can see this being released soon though.